# WordPress fails to store non-english characters

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, nginx

I have an issue with a friend's WordPress website I recently migrated to my personal web-server. I have never used WordPress besides setting up my blog (which runs fine). But with this website, I am having a hard time. It seems like every time we attempt to save a post or a page, the content gets saved as weird characters (boxes, question marks, etc).

Sounds like a pretty common issue people are having with WordPress but it's not. That's because the encoding issue only happens when saving something using the WordPress editor. For example, if I directly input greek characters via MySQL Workbench, they will be correctly displayed on the page. But if I edit the page, all non-english characters (even those that used to be displayed correctly), will be stored as gibberish. And by store I mean, I can see those characters looking like this: Î³Î¹Î inside the `wp_posts` table.

So WordPress can **read** non-English characters from the database but it cannot **write** non-english characters to the database.

`DB_COLLATE` is set to `utf8mb4_general_ci`
and
`DB_CHARSET` to `utf8mb4`.

MySQL Workbench reports the same for the database. 
My blog, that runs on the same server, using the same WordPress version and the same database, works fine.

Comment: i believe there is something not correct with your WordPress core file its might be modified some how.
WordPress can read and write non-English characters  that's for sure.
Try to install wordfence and scan the core files to check them

Answer (score 0):

Use `utf8_decode` and `utf8_encode` in save query method.

- http://php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-decode.php
- http://php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

Open  the file `wp-config.php` in the main directory of the website.

There is a line which should read `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');`

If not, change or add that.

Comment: If you mean `wp-config.php`, then yes I've already set `DB_CHARSET` to `utf8mb4`